MySQL Order subquery by the order that fields from another table come in
I have a custom form builder where admins can create fields and forms separately so that the fields are reusable on multiple forms. The fields can be reordered by admins at any time and have new fields added or existing ones removed, even after submissions have been made. I have 5 tables for this: forms, fields, a form_fields linking table, submissions, and a submission_fields table which is both a linking table and also contains the values of the submitted fields.
The problem is with the ordering of data with existing submissions if a field's position has been moved. In this SQLFiddle, I have simulated a submission for a form where the order of the fields was numerical (1 (first name), 2 (last name), 3 (email address), 4 (address), 5 (city), 6 (state), 7 (zip), and 8 (phone)), but then the phone number field (#8) was moved up under the email address field, changing the order to 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7.
-- INIT database
CREATE TABLE forms (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  title VARCHAR(200)
);

CREATE TABLE fields (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  label VARCHAR(200)
);

CREATE TABLE form_fields (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  form_id INT,
  field_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE submissions (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  form_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE submission_fields (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  submission_id INT,
  field_id INT,
  field_value VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO forms(title) VALUES ('Form 1');

INSERT INTO fields(label) VALUES ('First Name');
INSERT INTO fields(label) VALUES ('Last Name');
INSERT INTO fields(label) VALUES ('Email Address');
INSERT INTO fields(label) VALUES ('Address');
INSERT INTO fields(label) VALUES ('City');
INSERT INTO fields(label) VALUES ('State');
INSERT INTO fields(label) VALUES ('Zip');
INSERT INTO fields(label) VALUES ('Phone');

INSERT INTO form_fields(form_id, field_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO form_fields(form_id, field_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO form_fields(form_id, field_id) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO form_fields(form_id, field_id) VALUES (1, 8);
INSERT INTO form_fields(form_id, field_id) VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO form_fields(form_id, field_id) VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO form_fields(form_id, field_id) VALUES (1, 6);
INSERT INTO form_fields(form_id, field_id) VALUES (1, 7);

INSERT INTO submissions(form_id) VALUES (1);

INSERT INTO submission_fields(submission_id, field_id, field_value) VALUES (1, 1, 'Joe');
INSERT INTO submission_fields(submission_id, field_id, field_value) VALUES (1, 2, 'Smith');
INSERT INTO submission_fields(submission_id, field_id, field_value) VALUES (1, 3, 'joe@smith.com');
INSERT INTO submission_fields(submission_id, field_id, field_value) VALUES (1, 4, '123 Main St');
INSERT INTO submission_fields(submission_id, field_id, field_value) VALUES (1, 5, 'Somewhere');
INSERT INTO submission_fields(submission_id, field_id, field_value) VALUES (1, 6, 'CA');
INSERT INTO submission_fields(submission_id, field_id, field_value) VALUES (1, 7, '90210');
INSERT INTO submission_fields(submission_id, field_id, field_value) VALUES (1, 8, '555-555-5555');

-- QUERY database
SELECT
    submissions.id AS submission_id,
    submissions.form_id AS form_id,
    forms.title AS form_title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(form_fields.field_id, '') SEPARATOR '|') AS field_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(fields.label, '') SEPARATOR '|') AS field_labels,
    (
      SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(submission_fields.field_value, '') SEPARATOR '|')
      FROM
        submission_fields
      WHERE
        submission_fields.submission_id = submissions.id
    ) AS field_values
FROM
    submissions
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    forms
ON
    forms.id = submissions.form_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    form_fields
ON
    form_fields.form_id = submissions.form_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    fields
ON
    fields.id = form_fields.field_id
WHERE
    submissions.id = 1
GROUP BY
    submissions.id;

In the main query, everything comes back correctly. In the subqueries for field_ids and field_values, however, they come back in the original order. So I need to get those into the same order as they come back in the main query (field_values should have the phone number in the 4th position, as it is field ID 8 and appears in the 4th position in field_ids).

the order of items in a GROUP_CONCAT is totally arbitrary unless you include an ORDER BY argument to GROUP_CONCAT.  if the order you are seeing field_ids in happens to be what you expect, you cannot count on that continuing to be true.  so much of your question seems to assume there is some innate order that I can't tell if there is anything you are storing that should be used to determine the order.

The indexing of the tables you show -- quite inefficient.  If you expect to have millions of rows, we need to discuss further.

You can add ORDER BY form_fields.id ASC inside your GROUP_CONCAT to change the order of the result based on the order of the reference (form_fields.id).
Here is the modified query with the result you need: SQLFiddle
Note that I also removed the subquery and JOIN the submission_fields table instead to simplify the script and to easily order the result based on the reference.
Here is the complete script:
-- QUERY database

SELECT
    submissions.id AS submission_id,
    submissions.form_id AS form_id,
    forms.title AS form_title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(form_fields.field_id, '') ORDER BY form_fields.id ASC SEPARATOR '|') AS form_fields_field_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(fields.label, '') ORDER BY form_fields.id ASC SEPARATOR '|') AS field_labels,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(submission_fields.field_id, '') ORDER BY form_fields.id ASC SEPARATOR '|') AS field_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(submission_fields.field_value, '') ORDER BY form_fields.id ASC SEPARATOR '|') AS field_values
FROM
    submissions
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    forms
ON
    forms.id = submissions.form_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    form_fields
ON
    form_fields.form_id = submissions.form_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    fields
ON
    fields.id = form_fields.field_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    submission_fields
ON
    submission_fields.submission_id = submissions.id AND fields.id = submission_fields.field_id
WHERE
    submissions.id = 1
GROUP BY
    submissions.id;

